# how to implementing login using php files in cordova onsen ui

Tags: android, json, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

This is my first html5 mobile app and first time using angularjs. i already used javascript and jquery in my websites.

Now i have a problem. I want to implement Login(first time only) in my mobile app. How to do this ? I searched a lot and didnt get answer.

can anybody please give a sample code another wise please give some hint  for login with client side and serverside(php) code with username and password.

I want a easy method to login. is there any other methods?

and i have also see this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27401544/onsenui-angular-and-login)  but dont get it answer

thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Onsen UI has a great mobile first front end for Angular.js

There is a good tutorial on sitepoint. [Taking Your Cordova App Further with Onsen UI](http://www.sitepoint.com/taking-cordova-app-onsen-ui/)

Comment: please solve this Question answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28088758/json-shows-in-browser-but-not-show-in-mobile-application?noredirect=1