# JSON shows in browser, but not show in mobile application

Tags: android, json, angularjs, cordova

Hello i am use the angularjs for devloping application  and 
 this is my code  where I am use the

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" ng-app="myBusStopApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>My bus stop - Real time data</title> 
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">   
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('myBusStopApp', [])
.controller('myBusStopCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
   // $scope.realTimeData;
    var url ='http://eaglenew.comoj.com/JsonReturn.php';
 //   var url = "http://reis.trafikanten.no/reisrest/realtime/getrealtimedata/3010435" + "?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
    $http.get(url)
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.realTimeData = data;
        //console.log(data+"ddddddddddddddd");      
        });
}]);</script>
</head>
<body style="margin-top:2%;font-size:14px;font-family:Open Sans; padding-left:2%;padding-right:2%;">
<div ng-controller="myBusStopCtrl">
    <center>
    <div class="table-responsive" style="max-width:800px;">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr class="info">
            <th>Bus#</th>
            <th>Destination</th>
            <th>Wait time</th>          
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in realTimeData">
                <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                <td>{{item.email}}</td>
                <td>{{item | json }}</td>            
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In this code the JSON data are show in the  web beowser but when i am tried to the launch this in my phone the this is not show any data

**this is show this->**

{{item.id}}  {{item.email}}  {{item | json }}

error are not show in **console** in this situation what can i do please help me .... thanx in advance

Comment: check device is connect with internet

Comment: internet is available in device

Comment: are u open this link on webview............

Comment: this right show in web browser but data are not proper show in the mobile application

Comment: in m asking to u how to open this xml on mobile device like open in wenview or open in builtin browser

Comment: I am use the cordova and phonegap and onsen ui framwork  to use this for open in android application  this is my java code package com.example.onsenuimainfiles;

import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}

Comment: may be check out your pluging in device............

Comment: mean's .. i check the plugin in  eclipse

Comment: check pluginn in xml file

Comment: which plugin i check it out.... and wait sir

Comment: this is my plugin file sir<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<plugins>
 <plugin name="Device" value="com.phonegap.Device" />
</plugins>